# Killing a process once time limit exceeded

Tags: c, kill-process, waitpid

I've been working on the following code for quite some time, but can't really figure it out.
The task is to read a terminal command and to run it every x seconds; if the command hasn't finished within the waiting time, we want to kill the process and afterwards run the command again.
Any help would be really appreciated.
I'm pretty sure I'm not using waitpid() correctly; how would I go about using waitpid to achieve the goal?

Additionally, how would I go about detecting an error within a child process? The plan is to kill the parent process if an error occurred in a child process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int waitingTime;
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments provided. Please specify a command and exactly one parameter.");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    // -n parameter specified? If so, set the waiting time.
    if (argc == 5 && strcmp(argv[3], "-n") == 0) {
        waitingTime = atoi(argv[4]);
    } else {
        waitingTime = 5; // Default waiting time.
    }

    char* cmd = (char*)malloc(sizeof(argv[1]));
    cmd = argv[1];
    char* param = (char*)malloc(sizeof(argv[2]));
    param = argv[2];

    // Print the read command and its param
    printf("Command: %s, Parameter: %s, Interval: %d\n\n", cmd, param, waitingTime);    

    pid_t pid;

    for (;;) { 
        // Declared here for scope
        int secsWaited;
        secsWaited = 0;
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0) {
            pid = getpid();
            printf("==============\n");
            execlp(cmd, cmd, param, "/", (char *)NULL);
            printf("Excec failed; killing the proccess.");
            kill(pid, SIGKILL);
        } else if (pid > 0) {
            int status, code;
            for (;;) {
                code = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
            if (code == 0 && secsWaited >= waitingTime) {
                kill(pid, SIGKILL);
            printf("Child stopped");
            break;
        } else if (code == 0 && secsWaited < waitingTime) {
            secsWaited++;   
                    sleep(1);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            /*if (!WIFEXITED(status)) {
                printf("Time exceeding, stopping child.");
        // Get parent process id and kill it.
        kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
        }*/



            // Sleep for the specified time
            sleep(waitingTime - secsWaited);

        } else {
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }      

    free(cmd);
    free(param);       
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: any particular reason you're using C for this? Such a task would be much better suited for shell programming or higher level programming languages like python.

Comment: I'm asked to do it in C, it wasn't my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic was a bit too complicated (e.g. too many different `sleep` calls and `if/else` ladder logic).

Also, no need to `malloc` the `argv` strings--they can be used directly.

I've simplified it and restructured a bit to get it to work [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/*
 *
 */
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int waitingTime;

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments provided. Please specify a command and exactly one parameter.");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // -n parameter specified? If so, set the waiting time.
    if (argc == 5 && strcmp(argv[3], "-n") == 0) {
        waitingTime = atoi(argv[4]);
    }
    else {
        waitingTime = 5;                // Default waiting time.
    }

    char *cmd = argv[1];
    char *param = argv[2];

    // Print the read command and its param
    printf("Command: %s, Parameter: %s, Interval: %d\n\n",
        cmd, param, waitingTime);

    pid_t pid;
    int code = -1;
    int status;
    int killflg = 1;

    for (;;) {
        // Declared here for scope
        int secsWaited;

        secsWaited = 0;
        pid = fork();

        // stop on fork failure
        if (pid < 0) {
            killflg = 1;
            break;
        }

        // child process
        if (pid == 0) {
            pid = getpid();
            printf("==============\n");
#if 0
            execlp(cmd, cmd, param, "/", (char *) NULL);
#else
            execlp(cmd, cmd, param, (char *) NULL);
#endif
            printf("Excec failed; killing the proccess.");

// NOTE/BUG: this is the child so pid is zero, so killing it is wrong
#if 0
            kill(pid, SIGKILL);
#else
            exit(1);
#endif
        }

        killflg = 0;
        for (;;) {
            code = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
            if (code > 0)
                break;

            if (killflg)
                continue;

            secsWaited++;
            sleep(1);

            if (secsWaited >= waitingTime) {
                printf("timeout\n");
                kill(pid, SIGKILL);
                killflg = 1;
            }
        }

        if (! killflg)
            break;
    }

#if 0
    free(cmd);
    free(param);
#endif

    if (killflg)
        code = EXIT_FAILURE;
    else
        code = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    return code;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Right now, the program will stop after one iteration; if I remove the breakpoint at `if (! killflg)`, it will work as expected. Am I missing something or is this just a misunderstanding?

You are correct--my bad. I had missed the following in your question:

> The task is to read a terminal command and to run it every x seconds;

Change the `break` into `sleep(waitingTime - secsWaited)`.

---

But, a more robust way to keep track of elapsed time may be via two calls to `time(2)`:

After the `killflg = 0`, do: `time_t todbeg = time(NULL); time_t todelap;`. Then, you can get elapsed time [anywhere] with: `todelap = time(NULL) - todbeg;` [here, `todelap` is similar to `secsWaited`]. This may be better than incrementing `secsWaited`.

`time` only has seconds resolution. For more precision control, consider using `clock_gettime` [has nanosecond resolution].

Here's a function that I use a lot for elapsed time [in *fractional* seconds]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

double
tvgetf(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts);

    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    return sec;
}

/*
 *
 */
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int waitingTime;

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Invalid number of arguments provided. Please specify a command and exactly one parameter.");
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // -n parameter specified? If so, set the waiting time.
    if (argc == 5 && strcmp(argv[3], "-n") == 0) {
        waitingTime = atoi(argv[4]);
    }
    else {
        waitingTime = 5;                // Default waiting time.
    }

    char *cmd = argv[1];
    char *param = argv[2];

    // Print the read command and its param
    printf("Command: %s, Parameter: %s, Interval: %d\n\n", cmd, param, waitingTime);

    pid_t pid;
    int code = -1;
    int status;
    int killflg = 1;
    double todzero = tvgetf();

    for (;;) {
        // Declared here for scope
        double todbeg = tvgetf();
        double todelap;

        pid = fork();

        // stop on fork failure
        if (pid < 0) {
            killflg = 1;
            break;
        }

        // child process
        if (pid == 0) {
            pid = getpid();
            printf("============== (%.9f)\n",tvgetf() - todzero);
            execlp(cmd, cmd, param, (char *) NULL);
            printf("Excec failed; killing the proccess.");
            exit(1);
        }

        killflg = 0;
        for (;;) {
            code = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
            if (code > 0)
                break;

            if (killflg)
                continue;

            usleep(1000);

            todelap = tvgetf() - todbeg;
            if (todelap >= waitingTime) {
                printf("timeout\n");
                kill(pid, SIGKILL);
                killflg = 1;
            }
        }

        // do _not_ wait -- we already timed out
        if (killflg)
            continue;

        // get final elapsed time for this round and the amount of time
        // remaining until the next interval
        todelap = tvgetf() - todbeg;
        useconds_t time_to_wait = ((double) waitingTime - todelap) * 1e6;

        // wait until the next time period
        if (time_to_wait > 0)
            usleep(time_to_wait);
    }

    if (killflg)
        code = EXIT_FAILURE;
    else
        code = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    return code;
}
```

*Side note:* I used `usleep` here, but, although slightly more complex, it's considered better to use `nanosleep`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense and helped me understand the related commands. However, I do have one question left: Right now, the program will stop after one iteration; if I remove the breakpoint at "if ( !killflg)", it will work as expected. Am I missing something or is this just a misunderstanding?